# Update LiveTile when Song Changes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

Basically, I am using this sample.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask

An XAMLrenderingBackgroundTask which updates my live tile with album art, text, etc. Works great - however I can't get it to run when the song changes. I have no clue how I can trigger this task when the song changes.

I have a separate BackgroundTask that is continuously running and receives events for Song changes, etc. But I don't know of a way to trigger this XAMLrenderingBackgroundTask myself without adding triggers like System time changed, etc. It must be possible, I see other apps updating images on tiles when a song changes.

I tried implementing the XAMLrenderingBGTask with the Media BackgroundTask and attempting to update the live tile when the media changed but it crashes due to some call being marshalled from another thread which I kind of expected.

Now I am stuck. Here is my backgroundtask for media player, MediaOpened event should trigger tile change for new song, but I can't..

```
    public sealed class BackgroundAudioTask : IBackgroundTask 
    {
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        systemmediatransportcontrol = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        systemmediatransportcontrol.ButtonPressed += systemmediatransportcontrol_ButtonPressed;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.PropertyChanged += systemmediatransportcontrol_PropertyChanged;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPauseEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsNextEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPreviousEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsFastForwardEnabled = true;
        systemmediatransportcontrol.IsRewindEnabled = true;


        //Add handlers for MediaPlayer
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentStateChanged += Current_CurrentStateChanged;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.MediaFailed += mediaPlayer_MediaFailed;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.VolumeChanged += Current_VolumeChanged;

        BackgroundTaskStarted.Set();
        backgroundtaskrunning = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late :D 
you can use [This](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) to update tiles .
scenario 2 I think can help you .
in MediaOpened event you can update tile